# Unable to filter data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I tried to read data of my MySQL database, I created the fullcalendar and show up the event on calendar. However, it is unable to retrieve the data from my MySQL database.

The First php code :

```
     <?php require_once('conn.php'); ?>
     <?php $maxRows_RsCourse = 1000000;
        $pageNum_RsCourse = 0;
       if (isset($_GET['pageNum_RsCourse'])) {
        $pageNum_RsCourse = $_GET['pageNum_RsCourse'];
             }
        $startRow_RsCourse = $pageNum_RsCourse * $maxRows_RsCourse;

        mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
       $query_RsCourse = "SELECT * FROM tbl_course ORDER BY tcid ASC";
      $query_limit_RsCourse = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_RsCourse, $startRow_RsCourse, $maxRows_RsCourse);
      $RsCourse = mysql_query($query_limit_RsCourse, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
      $row_RsCourse = mysql_fetch_assoc($RsCourse);

        if (isset($_GET['totalRows_RsCourse'])) {
      $totalRows_RsCourse = $_GET['totalRows_RsCourse'];
} else {
     $all_RsCourse = mysql_query($query_RsCourse);
    $totalRows_RsCourse = mysql_num_rows($all_RsCourse);
}
    $totalPages_RsCourse = ceil($totalRows_RsCourse/$maxRows_RsCourse)-1;
    ?>
<?php

    $tbl_name="tbl_course"; // Table name 
    $totalcount = 0;

     // Connect to server and select database.
    mysql_connect("$hostname_conn", "$username_conn", "$password_conn")or die("cannot connect server "); 
    mysql_select_db("$database_conn")or die("unable to connect");

    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

            while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

            // echo "<table><tr>";
            // echo "<td>" . $rows['id'] . "</td><td>" . $rows['title'] . "</td><td>" . $rows['start'] . "</td><td>" . $rows['end'] . "</td><td>" . $rows['url'] . "</td><td>" . $rows['allDay'];
            // echo "</td></tr></table>";

            $event[$totalcount]['tcid']=$rows['tcid'];
            $event[$totalcount]['courseid']=$rows['courseid'];
            $event[$totalcount]['coursename']=$rows['coursename'];
            $event[$totalcount]['startdate']=$rows['startdate'];
            $event[$totalcount]['starttime']=$rows['starttime'];
            $event[$totalcount]['enddate']=$rows['enddate'];
            $event[$totalcount]['endtime']=$rows['endtime'];
            $event[$totalcount]['allday']=$rows['allday'];

            $totalcount++;

            }

            for ($i=0; $i < $totalcount; $i++)
            {

            $tmp1 = explode("-",$event[$i]['startdate']);
            $tmp2 = explode(":",$event[$i]['starttime']);

            // 0 = hour, 1 = minutes, 2 = seconds,

            $x = 0;

            foreach ($tmp1 as $date_values_1)
            {
                $event_start_date[$i][$x] = $date_values_1;
                $x++;
            }

            $y = 0;

            foreach ($tmp2 as $time_values_1)
            {
                $event_start_time[$i][$y] = $time_values_1;
                $y++;
            }

            $tmp3 = explode("-",$event[$i]['enddate']);
            $tmp4 = explode(":",$event[$i]['endtime']);

            $a = 0;

            foreach ($tmp3 as $date_values_2)
            {
                $event_end_date[$i][$a] = $date_values_2;
                $a++;
            }

            $b = 0;

            foreach ($tmp4 as $time_values_2)
            {
                $event_end_time[$i][$b] = $time_values_2;
                $b++;
            }
            }
            ?>
            <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
            <!-- saved from url=(0046)http://localhost/calendar/demos/db_display.php -->
            <HTML><HEAD>
            <META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type>
            <link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
            <script src='js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
            <script src='js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js'></script>
            <script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
            <SCRIPT>

            $(document).ready(function() {

                var start_year = new Array(<?php $totalcount?>);
                var start_month = new Array(<?php $totalcount?>);
                var start_day = new Array(<?php $totalcount?>);

                var end_year =new Array(<?php $totalcount?>);
                var end_month =new Array(<?php $totalcount?>);
                var end_day =new Array(<?php $totalcount?>);
                var start_hour =new Array(<?php $totalcount?>);
                var start_mins =new Array(<?php $totalcount?>);

                var end_hour =new Array(<?php $totalcount?>);   
                var end_mins =new Array(<?php $totalcount?>);

            <?php 
            $k = 0;

            for ($k=0; $k < $totalcount; $k++) {?>




            start_year[<?php echo $k?>] =<?php echo $event_start_date[$k][0] ?>;
            start_month[<?php echo $k?>] =<?php echo $event_start_date[$k][1] ?>;
            start_day[<?php echo $k?>] =<?php echo $event_start_date[$k][2]?>;

            end_year[<?php echo $k?>] =<?php echo $event_end_date[$k][0]?>;
            end_month[<?php echo $k?>] =<?php echo $event_end_date[$k][1]?>;
            end_day[<?php echo $k?>] =<?php echo $event_end_date[$k][2]?>;

            start_hour[<?php echo $k?>] =<?php echo $event_start_time[$k][0] ?>;
            start_mins[<?php echo $k?>] =<?php echo $event_start_time[$k][1] ?>;

            end_hour[<?php echo $k?>] =<?php echo $event_end_time[$k][0]?>;
            end_mins[<?php echo $k?>] =<?php echo $event_end_time[$k][1]?>;

            <?php } ?>


                        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                        editable: false,
                        events: [



            <?php $j = 0;

            for ($j=0; $j < $totalcount; $j++)
            {
            ?>


            <?php

            if ($event[$j]['allday'] == 0){?>

                                { title: '<?php echo $event[$j]['courseid'];?> <?php echo $event[$j]['coursename'];?>',
                                start: new Date(start_year[<?php echo $j?>],start_month[<?php echo $j?>]-1,start_day[<?php echo $j?>],start_hour[<?php echo $j?>],start_mins[<?php echo $j?>]),

                                end: new Date(end_year[<?php echo $j?>],end_month[<?php echo $j?>]-1,end_day[<?php echo $j?>],end_hour[<?php echo $j?>],end_mins[<?php echo $j?>]) , url: 'mg_course.php?courseid=<?php echo $event[$j]['courseid']; ?>'
                                /*
                                end: new Date(end_year[<?php echo $j?>],end_month[<?php echo $j?>]-1,end_day[<?php echo $j?>],end_hour[<?php echo $j?>],end_mins[<?php echo $j?>]) , url: 'mg_course.php?courseid=<?php echo $_GET['courseid']; ?>'
                                */

                                },                  
            <?php } ?>                  
            <?php if ($event[$j]['allday'] == 1) {?>

                                { title: '<?php echo $event[$j]['courseid'];?> <?php echo $event[$j]['coursename'];?>',
                                start: new Date(start_year[<?php echo $j?>],start_month[<?php echo $j?>]-1,start_day[<?php echo $j?>],start_hour[<?php echo $j?>],start_mins[<?php echo $j?>]),

                                end: new Date(end_year[<?php echo $j?>],end_month[<?php echo $j?>]-1,end_day[<?php echo $j?>],end_hour[<?php echo $j?>],end_mins[<?php echo $j?>]), url: 'mg_course.php?courseid=<?php echo $event[$j]['courseid']; ?>',
                                /*
                                end: new Date(end_year[<?php echo $j?>],end_month[<?php echo $j?>]-1,end_day[<?php echo $j?>],end_hour[<?php echo $j?>],end_mins[<?php echo $j?>]), url: 'mg_course.php?courseid=<?php echo $_GET['courseid']; ?>',
                                */
                                allDay: 'false'
                                },      

            <?php } ?>




            <?php }?>


                            {}
                        ]
                    });

                });

            </SCRIPT>

            <STYLE>BODY {
                TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN-TOP: 40px; FONT-FAMILY: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif; FONT-SIZE: 14px
            }
            #calendar {
                MARGIN: 0px auto; WIDTH: 900px
            }
            </STYLE>

            <META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 8.00.6001.19412"></HEAD>
            <BODY>
            <DIV id=calendar></DIV></BODY></HTML>
```

Here is display event details php:

```
                                        <?php require_once('conn.php'); ?>
                <?php
                session_start();
                $MM_authorizedUsers = "";
                $MM_donotCheckaccess = "true";

                // *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
                function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
                  // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
                  $isValid = False; 

                  // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username. 
                  // Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
                  if (!empty($UserName)) { 
                    // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login. 
                    // Parse the strings into arrays. 
                    $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
                    $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
                    if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
                      $isValid = true; 
                    } 
                    // Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
                    if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
                      $isValid = true; 
                    } 
                    if (($strUsers == "") && true) { 
                      $isValid = true; 
                    } 
                  } 
                  return $isValid; 
                }
                ?>
                <?php
                $totalRows_RsEnrol = 0;

                if ( isset($_POST['courseid']) ) {
                $_GET['courseid'] = $_POST['courseid'];
                $_GET['courseid'] = $_GET['courseid'] * 1;
                if (is_integer($_GET['courseid']) ) {
                $maxRows_RsEnrol = 10000;
                $pageNum_RsEnrol = 0;
                if (isset($_GET['pageNum_RsEnrol'])) {
                  $pageNum_RsEnrol = $_GET['pageNum_RsEnrol'];
                }
                $startRow_RsEnrol = $pageNum_RsEnrol * $maxRows_RsEnrol;

                mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
                $query_RsEnrol = "SELECT * FROM 'tbl_enroll' WHERE 'tbl_enroll'.'courseid' = '".$_GET['courseid']."'";
                //$query_RsEnrol = sprintf("SELECT erid, courseid, staffid FROM tbl_enroll WHERE courseid = %s ORDER BY staffid ASC", $_GET['courseid']);
                $query_limit_RsEnrol = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_RsEnrol, $startRow_RsEnrol, $maxRows_RsEnrol);
                $RsEnrol = mysql_query($query_limit_RsEnrol, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
                $row_RsEnrol = mysql_fetch_assoc($RsEnrol);

                if (isset($_GET['totalRows_RsEnrol'])) {
                  $totalRows_RsEnrol = $_GET['totalRows_RsEnrol'];
                } else {
                  $all_RsEnrol = mysql_query($query_RsEnrol);
                  $totalRows_RsEnrol = mysql_num_rows($all_RsEnrol);
                }
                $totalPages_RsEnrol = ceil($totalRows_RsEnrol/$maxRows_RsEnrol)-1;
                } else { $totalRows_RsEnrol = 0;}

                } 

                /******************************************************************************************************/
                elseif (isset($_GET['courseid']) && !empty($_GET['courseid']) ) {
                $_GET['courseid'] = $_GET['courseid']*1;
                if (is_integer($_GET['courseid'])){
                $maxRows_RsEnrol = 1000000;
                $pageNum_RsEnrol = 0;
                if (isset($_GET['pageNum_RsEnrol'])) {
                  $pageNum_RsEnrol = $_GET['pageNum_RsEnrol'];
                }
                $startRow_RsEnrol = $pageNum_RsEnrol * $maxRows_RsEnrol;

                mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
                $query_RsEnrol = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tbl_enroll WHERE courseid IN ( SELECT courseid FROM tbl_course WHERE courseid = %s) ORDER BY erid ASC", $_GET['courseid']);
                //$query_RsEnrol = sprintf("SELECT erid, courseid, staffid FROM tbl_enroll WHERE courseid=%s ORDER BY staffid ASC", $_GET['courseid']);
                $query_limit_RsEnrol = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_RsEnrol, $startRow_RsEnrol, $maxRows_RsEnrol);
                $RsEnrol = mysql_query($query_limit_RsEnrol, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
                $row_RsEnrol = mysql_fetch_assoc($RsEnrol);

                if (isset($_GET['totalRows_RsEnrol'])) {
                  $totalRows_RsEnrol = $_GET['totalRows_RsEnrol'];
                } else {
                  $all_RsEnrol = mysql_query($query_RsEnrol);
                  $totalRows_RsEnrol = mysql_num_rows($all_RsEnrol);
                }
                $totalPages_RsEnrol = ceil($totalRows_RsEnrol/$maxRows_RsEnrol)-1;

                } else {$totalRows_RsEnrol=0;}
                }
                ?>
                <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <link href="../../css/style_new.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <title></title>
                </head>

                <body>
                <br />
                <table width="322" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="171"><img src="../../Images/logo.gif" width="144" height="34"></td>

                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center" ><h2>Training Program</h2></td>
                  </tr>

                </table>
                <div class="containers" align=">
                  <div class="header">
                    <p align="center" class="style2">Enrolment</p>
                <h5 class="../css/new_style.css" align="left"> 
                <table align="center" width="116%"  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" >

                <tr align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" >
                    <td width="16%">Enrolment ID</td> 
                    <td width="50%">Course ID</td>
                    <td width="14%">Staff ID</td>
                    <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr align="center" bgcolor="#dfdfdf" >
                    <td><?php echo $row_RsEnrol['erid']; ?></td>
                    <td align="left">&nbsp;<?php echo $row_RsEnrol['courseid']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_RsEnrol['staffid']; ?></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                </body>
                </html>
```

It is unable to filter data on Calendar.

I am really appreciated for your help.

Comment: Do not use `mysql_ ...` functions anymore. They are deprecated.

Comment: I wish, I could help you. But there is too much code. Can you minimize the code in the question, and show only relevant part. Debugging yourself as much as possible.

Comment: Please let me know how to do it. Any ideas for me. Thanks.

Comment: I have fixed this issue. Thanks a lot.